# Como abrir na mesma guia um documento HTML vindo do fetch?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

Estou criando um site de enigmas em que a cada enigma, o usuário deverá inserir uma resposta no `prompt` e essa resposta será enviada ao servidor por requisição POST com a função `fetch`.

No lado do servidor, a resposta será verificada e caso ela esteja correta, eu retorno uma nova página HTML contendo um novo enigma. Caso a reposta do usuário esteja errada, o servidor retorna o código 403 para dizer que era uma resposta errada.

Já no lado do cliente, eu quero verificar se a resposta era certa ou errada. Se a resposta for incorreta será emitido um `alert` e se a resposta estiver certa, eu quero que o navegador renderize a nova página enviada pelo servidor.

O problema é que eu não sei como faço para redirecionar o cliente para essa página que o servidor enviou.

O que eu estava fazendo antes era escrever o texto recebido com o `document.write`, mas chega uma hora que não dá certo pois o conteúdo dos arquivos se acumulam na página.

```js
function sendAnswer(){

    const answer = prompt("Digite sua resposta:").toLowerCase();
    if(!answer){return;}

    fetch("/", {
        method: "post",
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify({answer: answer, fase: sessionStorage.fase})

    }).then(function(response){

        if (response.status != 200){
            alert("Resposta Errada!");
            return;
        }

        response.text().then(function(text){
            document.write(text);
        });
                    
    });
}
```

O que eu quero é mudar o conteúdo da página por completo pelo arquivo HTML recebido do servidor. Como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: O HTML que o servidor retorna contém um `<head>` (é um documento completo)? Ou é somente um trecho do HTML? Na página que o usuário submete a resposta, você tem alguma `div` que pode ser usada para inserir o HTML respondido pelo servidor? Ou você realmente deseja trocar o conteúdo todo da página?

Comment: É um documento completo. Eu gostaria de trocar todo o conteúdo da página como se eu estivesse fazendo um redirecionamento com o `location`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por este trecho:

> O que eu estava fazendo antes era escrever o texto recebido com o `document.write`, mas chega uma hora que não dá certo pois o conteúdo dos arquivos se acumulam na página.

Creio que você conseguiu trocar o conteúdo da página pela resposta da requisição assíncrona. O seu problema então deve ser como limpar o documento antes de executar um outro `document.write`. Nesse caso, basta utilizar antes do `document.write`, o método [`document.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open), que remove todos os nós do DOM presentes no documento.

Algo assim:

```js
response.text().then(function(text) {
  document.open();
  document.write(text);
});
```

Veja exemplos similares. Primeiro, sem o `document.open`:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  document.write(Date.now() + '<br />');
}, 750);
```

Com o `document.open` antes do `document.write`:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  document.open();
  document.write(Date.now() + '<br />');
}, 750);
```

Comment: Obrigado Luiz, isso funcionou mas é possível adicionar na resposta como fazer isso só que sem apagar o arquivo anterior? Tipo assim, quando o usuário clicar no botão de voltar (setinha para esquerda do navegador) ele ir para a página anterior (antes da página recebida do `fetch`).

Comment: Quando você usa o `document.write` você não há como recuperar o estado anterior da página (não é uma nova página, é a **mesma** página, só que sobrescrita). O único meio de poder "voltar à página anterior" seria armazenar o HTML atual em uma variável antes de alterá-lo.

Comment: Ao que me parece, talvez seja mais interessante no seu caso não utilizar AJAX nesse caso, mas sim requisições `POST` por `<form>`. Elas te permitem a mudança da página muito mais facilmente, além de permitirem, de fato, voltar à _página anterior_.